# Sum results of drop down list in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am using drop-down lists for the observation, self-practice, and teaching tabs, and I would like to total the amount of time in column J. Is there a formula that will allow me to do this?

[image: screenshot of spreadsheet]

Comment: Does the "minutes" have to be in the drop down list?  If it is always minutes, and you just want it to display the word, then you could apply number format like `0 " minutes"`.  Then you could have numbers that could be summed without any special formulas.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is very simple if the cells only contain numbers and no other characters. If this were the case the following formula would go in cell `J2` and could be copied drug down automatically updating all the row references for the current row total:

`=SUM(G2:I2)`

This is the typical way Excel is used, one idea per cell. The labels and units are specified elsewhere, such as column headings.

However, in the stated problem, a formula is needed to isolate the number in the text. To reduce the complexity, we'll assume the number is before any other characters (leading spaces are ok). We will further assume there is at least one space between the number and any following character(s).
This solution allows for empty cells, leading spaces, multiple spaces and a number by itself (or with just spaces before and/or after the number).

`=IFERROR( NUMBERVALUE( LEFT( TRIM(F2) & " ", FIND( " ", TRIM(F2) & " " ) - 1)), 0) + IFERROR( NUMBERVALUE( LEFT( TRIM(G2) & " ", FIND( " ", TRIM(G2) & " ") - 1)) ,0) + IFERROR( NUMBERVALUE( LEFT( TRIM(H2) & " ", FIND( " ", TRIM(H2) & " ") -1 )), 0)`

Very convoluted, right?!
Here is a slightly more compact version but it is a special formula called an *array formula*. After pasting it into the cell, perform a special <kbd>Enter</kbd> key combination to make it an array formula. Otherwise Excel may say something is wrong with the formula or the results may be incorrect.

`=SUM( IFERROR( NUMBERVALUE( LEFT( TRIM(F2:H2) & " ", FIND( " ", TRIM(F2:H2) & " " ) - 1)), 0))`

Once the formula is pasted into the cell, make it an array formula by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Enter</kbd>. This is sometimes referred to by the acronym for this key press combination CSE (Control Shift Enter).
Everytime an array formula is edited, press CSE.